# How to cleanup Windows.Forms Handles?

Tags: c#, winforms, handle

I have a C# application that creates many System.Windows.Forms.Panel and System.Windows.Forms.Control objects.  I’ve been simply letting them go out of scope assuming that the GC would clean things up for me and that's been working for several years.  However, as the data has been growing I’m now getting a Win32 Exception: 0x80004005, Error creating window handle.

I added calls to GC.Collect() to see if was a Garbage Collection issue, but that didn’t help.  I’m guessing that things (i.e. Handles) are not getting cleaned up as I expect.  Do I need to do something to clean up the Windows Handles created by the Forms derived classes?

All code is standard C# code.  No C++, VB or other languages.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Task Manager's Details tab can show a column with the number of GDI Handles and User32 Handles - please tell us what it reports for those for your process. Additionally, there can be many different reasons for why `CreateWindow` fails with `0x80004005` besides handle-exhaustion.  Also, you're conflating GC collection with finalization and `IDisposable` - while they're all related, you cannot assume that `GC.Collect()`  is a magic cure-all: it isn't).

Comment: `Form.Controls` automatically cleans up child controls when the parent is disposed. What do you mean by "go out of scope" are you at least disposing the parent? Please show relevant code.

Comment: @Charlieface Unlss you do something silly as `[Control].Controls.Clear()` then fill the collection again, then, well, rinse and repeat -- If you create graphic objects, you're responsible for disposing of these objects, the GC cannot help you

Comment: @Jimi In `System.Drawing`, types like `Pen` and `Brush` have finalizers that _do_ call `Dispose()` which in-turn release GDI resources if they were not explicitly disposed via `IDisposable.Dispose` - but, yes, it is bad-practice to rely on this behaviour: if a type is `IDiposable` then it should have a defined lifetime with explicit `.Dispose` call or `using` block/statement.

Comment: @Dai All System::Drawing stuff has finalizers. I know that the GC is extremely efficient. When it can be. The OP is creating (many) Controls. As I mentioned, if you call `Controls.Clear()` and these Controls hold unmanaged resources of some kind, the GC won't do anything (because it can't). Hence, you have to dispose of all the unmanaged resources you have created, then the GC can help (as of now, even with `Controls.Clear()`). This assuming these Controls are not leaking while custom-drawing something, but this just accelerates the auto-termination of the application

Comment: If you are relying on the GC and Finalizers, you are likely doing it wrong (and, adding GC.Collect calls can slow down your app, pushing objects into Gen2). First find out what kind of handles you are leaking. Then go through your code making sure you Dispose everything you can (I tend to forget to Dispose dialog boxes (`myForm.ShowDialog()`)

Comment: Thanks everyone.  As suggested, I was doing something silly - Controls.Clear().  Now disposing of objects before clearing and all good.